# How do I edit a complex entity via dynamically loaded AJAX-forms?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a "profile" entity with a field "education" (to get started). That field contains various input fields that describe the "education". At the moment I have "institution" and "year". I created that field with the Field API in a dedicated module and attached it to my "profile" entity (currently this is a profile2 bundle). The entity form works as expected, the "education" field widget is included and I can add multiple "education" entries. I can view my entity and the fields get formatted, and I can edit my entity and the form widgets get rendered.

```
--profile entity
----education field
------education a
--------institution a
--------year a
------education b
--------institution b
--------year b
```

But I do not like the all or nothing approach here. There are going to be many different fields and I want to display the "profile" entity with various "edit" and "add new entry" buttons, which should load the specified field form widget via AJAX. The profile page on xing.com is a good example of what I am trying to achieve.

Is this possible with the fields form widget and Field API alone, or do I have to implement the ajax callback via a menu hook, which returns a form with the needed input fields? Can I even use my "education" field in that scenario or do I have to work with the entity API and database API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forms that FieldAPI can build for you automatically are useful but not terribly flexible. If you're interested in building out a really dynamic form, you're probably better off creating your own from scratch and simply creating/saving the entity programmatically once the finished form is submitted.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. I don't use the "education" field. Instead I create a "education" entity and use the Form API and Entity API to relate "education" entities n:1 to a "profile" entity.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module?  They have sample code for Ajax forms, using the FormAPI.

Comment: I did and I will soon post my approach. Bottom line: I did not use Field API at all. I used Form API with standard ajax page callbacks and Entity API to persist the form values.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully made a hierarchical select with ajax on a profile2 form used in registration.

```
// implementation of hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()    
function impact_registration_form_profile2_edit_library_registration_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
$form['profile_library_registration']['field_library_reg_state']['und']['#options'] = _impact_registration_library_states();
$form['profile_library_registration']['field_library_reg_state']['und']['#ajax'] = array(
                          'callback' => 'impact_registration_state_change_callback',
                          'wrapper' => 'name-select',
                        );
        $selected = isset($form_state['values']['profile_library_registration']['field_library_reg_state']['und'][0]['value']) ? $form_state['values']['profile_library_registration']['field_library_reg_state']['und'][0]['value'] : '';
    $form['profile_library_registration']['field_library_reg_system']['und']['#options'] = _impact_registration_library_names($selected);
    $form['profile_library_registration']['field_library_reg_system']['und']['#prefix'] = "<div id='name-select'>";
    $form['profile_library_registration']['field_library_reg_system']['und']['#suffix'] = "</div>";
        }
    function impact_registration_state_change_callback(&$form, $form_state) {
    return $form['profile_library_registration']['field_library_reg_system']['und'];
            }
```

When I select `field_library_reg_state`, AJAX returns `field_library_reg_system`, with a default value based on `field_library_reg_state`'s value in `$form_state`.  This is all adapted from the ajax example.  Now, what isn't working for me is adding an additional ajax call on `field_library_reg_system` so that it pre-populates a text box.  The documentation for doing this is non existent, I don't understand how profile2 and entity forms work differently than regular forms in drupal.  Which array elements are we supposed to target for the wrapper and callback?